# android java.lang.NullPointerException - I think I've instantiated every object

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've searched for hours on this null pointer exception but with to no avail. From what I've read there seems to be some object that has not yet been instantiated. I've revised my code over and over but I can't find where I've gone wrong. If I comment out the for loop containing the compTurn(); in onCreate(); then it gets to the main screen but obviously doesn't perform the function I need it too.

Thank you in advance :)

```
package com.hunsdale.cognitive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    // Initialise ArrayLists
    static ArrayList<Integer> Computer;
    static ArrayList<Integer> Player;

    // Initialise Computer's Arraylist Iterator
    static Iterator<Integer> CompIt;

    // Initialise computer's pick and user's pick for arraylist
    static int compPick, userPick, level;

    // Initialise counter for score
    static int counter;

    // Initialise random number generator and boolean(for next level
    // advance)
    static Random rand;

    // Initialise sounds for buttons
    static MediaPlayer Mblue, Mgreen, Mred, Morange, Mturn;

    // Initialise buttons
    static ImageView blue, green, red, orange, turnSwitch;

    // Initialise string to show their score to the user
    TextView score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set content = main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Instantiate buttons
        blue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blue_button);
        blue.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.green_btn);
        green.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        red = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red_btn);
        red.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        orange = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.orange_btn);
        orange.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        // Instantiate button sounds
        Mblue = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.bubble);
        Mgreen = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.release);
        Mred = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.texture_scratch);
        Morange = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.whistle_scratch);

        // Instantiate score display
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        // Instantiate ArrayLists
        Computer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        compPick = 0;
        userPick = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

            compTurn();
        }

    }

    public static void compTurn() {

        if (Player.equals(Computer)) {

            level++;

            Mblue.reset();
            Mgreen.reset();
            Mred.reset();
            Morange.reset();

            Player = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            counter = 0;

            // the buttons cannot be clicked
            blue.setEnabled(false);
            green.setEnabled(false);
            red.setEnabled(false);
            orange.setEnabled(false);

            compPick = rand.nextInt(4);
            Computer.add(compPick);


            for (Iterator<Integer> CompIt = Computer.iterator(); CompIt.hasNext();) {
                Integer i = CompIt.next();

                if (i == 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_hghlight);
                    Mblue.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.cst_btn_blue);
                    Mblue.reset();

                } else if (i == 1) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    green.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_green_highlight);
                    Mgreen.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    green.setImageResource(R.drawable.cst_btn_green);
                    Mgreen.reset();

                } else if (i == 2) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    red.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_red_highlight);
                    Mred.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    red.setImageResource(R.drawable.cst_btn_red);
                    Mred.reset();

                } else if (i == 3) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    orange.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_orange_highlight);
                    Morange.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    orange.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_btn_orange2);
                    Morange.reset();

                }
            }
        } else if (counter < Computer.size()) {
            enableUserTurn(true);
            counter++;
        }

    }

    public static void enableUserTurn(boolean buttonsEnabled) {

        // enable buttons to be clicked
        blue.setEnabled(buttonsEnabled);
        green.setEnabled(buttonsEnabled);
        red.setEnabled(buttonsEnabled);
        orange.setEnabled(buttonsEnabled);

    }

    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.blue_button:
                Mblue.start();
                Player.add(counter, 0);
                if (Player.indexOf(counter) == (Computer.indexOf(counter))) {

                    compTurn();

                } else {
                    score.setText("Fail");
                }
                break;

            case R.id.green_btn:
                Mgreen.start();
                Player.add(counter, 1);
                if (Player.indexOf(counter) == (Computer.indexOf(counter))) {

                    compTurn();

                } else {
                    score.setText("Fail");
                }
                break;

            case R.id.red_btn:
                Mred.start();
                Player.add(counter, 2);
                if (Player.indexOf(counter) == (Computer.indexOf(counter))) {

                    compTurn();

                } else {
                    score.setText("Fail");
                }

                break;

            case R.id.orange_btn:
                Morange.start();
                Player.add(counter, 3);
                Morange.reset();
                if (Player.indexOf(counter) == (Computer.indexOf(counter))) {

                    compTurn();

                } else {
                    score.setText("Fail");
                }

                break;
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Dump content of logcat here

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` on ui thread must be removed

Comment: Try to keep yourself to java conventions: fields and methods start with a lowercase letter, classes start with an uppercase letter. This helps in readability. Furthermore, do not keep static references to your `View`s. This might lead to memory leakage.

Comment: read your stacktrace, it tells you were the null is, which, given that this line only contains 1 object that would cause an NPE if null should tell you what is null quite quickly.

Comment: Post your logcat please..It would be really helpfull to find the errors from logcat..

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this:

```
if (Player.equals(Computer))
```

You missed creating object `Player` and it is null. If you change it to

```
if (Computer.equals(Player))
```

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `Player` before it's initialized.

Do this:

```
// Instantiate ArrayLists
        Computer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Player = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        compPick = 0;
        userPick = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

            compTurn();
        }
        ...
```